# Using while true to avoid nested conditionals - "standard in complex selection"?

Tags: design-patterns, complexity-theory

I recently came across the following pattern while reviewing someone's code:

```
while True:
   if not a.b:
      break

   if sum(b) > 1:
      x = a.c
      break
   break
```

I questioned the use of the `while` construct when not iterating anything. The answer from the coder was that this pattern avoids nested conditionals, and is a "standard pattern in complex selection."

## Questions

- Does this pattern have a name?
- What exactly is "complex selection"?

Answer (score 1):

I have not heard of such a pattern. But I think "complex selections" need to be simplified rather than complicated. I rather agree with the following quote from [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epattis/ICS-31/lectures/while/while.txt):

> Some experienced programmers (and educators) like to avoid using `while True` with
> `if/break`, but I am fine with this usage. In fact, I think it is easier for
> beginners (and sometimes even experienced programmers) to first just write the
> loop (not having to think: we always write it as while True) and then worry
> about what the body of the loop should compute, and how/where to test for
> termination. If it so happens the `if/break` is first in the loop (it actually
> is for a surprising number of loops) then we can perform the transformation.
>
> Where this advice goes wrong in the hands of beginners is that they often write
> multiple `if/breaks` inside their `while True` loops that make these loops
> complicated and very hard to understand. The most imporant part of a loop is
> how it terminates. It is an extraordinary `while True` loop that requires more
> than one `if/break`, so you should be skeptical that your code is simple if it has
> multiple `if/break` statements.

Comment: I believe the OP's point is that it is *not* a loop

Answer (score 0):

The alternatives are nested, but on the same level as a while/if-comparison.

```
# alternatives
if a.b and sum(b) > 1:
    x = a.c
    
if a.b:
    if sum(b) > 1:
        x = a.c
```

It only does make sense if you add more if statements, but you gain readability because the if statements are aligned, but it is possible that you will confuse some code reader, because they will not understand why the while loop will end with a break (the last one). So this way uses a loop 'just to get the break statements'.

```
while True:
    if not a.b:
        break
        
    if not a.c:
        break
        
    if not b:
        break
        
    if sum(b) > 1:
        x = a.c
        break
    break
        
    
    if a.b and a.c and b and sum(b) > 1:
        x = a.c
    
    if a.b:
        if a.c:
            if b:
                if sum(b) > 1:
                    x = a.c
```

In a normal function/method you would normally use guard causes for clarity and easy if's. This seems to be a way to use this structure outside a function by adding a while/break statement or if you do not want to return anything in a function, because you want to change the "selection" in some way in the same function.

Comment: So it may be a form of guard clauses.